# Flask: call function with parameters from form action

Tags: python, flask

in `routes.py` I have a function:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/makecsc_relocation') 
def makecsc_relocation(csc_post_index):
    ... 
    makeCscRelocationRep(repname, csc_post_index)
    return send_file(repname+'.xlsx', as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=repname+' '+csc_post_index+'.xlsx')
```

in `index`, I have the following:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
...
sForm = """<form action="makecsc_relocation">
                             Enter postal code here: <input type="text" name="post_index" value=""><br>
                             <input type="submit" value="Download report" ><br>
                             </form>"""
```

If I use function that has no parameters in `<form action="">` and pass to it an empty `input` value, everything works fine, but as I tried to pass `input post_index` as an argument to that function, I get Internal Server Error with following URL:
`http://myservername/makecsc_relocation?post_index=452680`

How do I fix that?

Comment: You can't have both functions registered as `@app.route('/')`, that's an error. Are you sure that the `makecsc_relocation` view function has those exact registrations?

Comment: But only *the last registration* wins. You replaced the registration for the `/` path, pointing to `makecsc_relocation` and replaced it with one that points to `index`. This is just confusing, remove one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution:

1. Added `POST` method to the form

```
sForm = """<form action="makecsc_relocation" method="post">
                             Enter postal code here: <input type="text" name="post_index" value=""><br>
                             <input type="submit" value="Download report" ><br>
                             </form>"""
```

2. In function `makecsc_relocation`, I added following string:

```
csc_post_index = request.form['post_index']
```

and passed that to `makeCscRelocationRep`

Answer (score 1):

Function parameters are always **path parameters**, the `<parametername>` components in the route path you register with `@app.route()`. You don't have such parameters, so don't give your function any parameters. See [*Variable Rules*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/#variable-rules) in the Flask Quickstart.

*Query* parameters (the key=value pairs from a form, put after the `?` in the URL) end up in [`request.args`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Request.args):

```
@app.route('/makecsc_relocation') 
def makecsc_relocation():
    csc_post_index = request.args.get('post_index')  # can return None
    # ... 
    makeCscRelocationRep(repname, csc_post_index)
    return send_file(repname+'.xlsx', as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=repname+' '+csc_post_index+'.xlsx')
```

See [*The Request Object*](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#the-request-object) section of the Quickstart.

- Use `request.args.get(...)` if a value is optional, or if you need to convert it from a string to a different type at the same type.
- Use `request.args[...]` if it is an error to not provide the value. If the query parameter is missing, a 400 Bad Request HTTP error response is given to the client.

See the [Werkzeug `MultiDict` documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict) on how this mapping works in detail.